# How can I fix this Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'String' and '[Any]?'

Tags: swift, ternary-operator

I have the following lines of code:

```
let string:String = ""
let extracted_data:String! = (response?.extracted_data == nil) ? "" : response?.extracted_data
string.append("\(extracted_data)")
```

`extracted_data` is a `[Any]`. I can't figure out why I am getting this error:

> Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'String' and '[Any]?'

Comment: Your expected type is in String and response?.extracted_data is a kind of [array]

Comment: `[Any]` is an array and is not related to `String`. What static type is `Any`?

Comment: @anilkukdeja could you please explain what i'm doing wrong with this code. I have tried change the string to [Array] but no luck either

Answer (score 2):

You should be parsing your variable as a [Any] type of array and later on if you know that your array contains string type you should be doing like this. Take a first element out of array and set your value

```
response?.extracted_data?.first as? String ?? "Default Value if string is not present"
```

Answer (score 1):

The values returned by the ternary operator `? :` need to be the same type, because Swift needs to know at compile time what type `extracted_data` will be.  You are attempting to return either a `String` or `[Any]?`.  To fix this, return an empty array `[]` instead of an empty string `""` for the `nil` case.  Also, you need to unwrap `response` so that `response!.extracted_data` returns `[Any]` instead of `[Any]?`.  Although force unwrapping with `!` can lead to crashes, this is safe because you already know `response` is not `nil` due to your check.

```
var string: String = ""  // This needs to be a var for append to work
let extracted_data = response?.extracted_data == nil ? [] : response!.extracted_data
string.append("\(extracted_data)")

print(string)
```

---

Now look at this line:

```
let extracted_data = response?.extracted_data == nil ? [] : response!.extracted_data
```

Swift has a better way of doing that with a special *nil coalescing operator* `??`.  It is used to unwrap an optional value or to supply a default value for when that value is `nil`.  Using `??`, the line becomes:

```
let extracted_data = response?.extracted_data ?? []
```

---

I assume this is a simplified example, because you could just assign to `string` instead of appending.  In either case, string needs to be a `var` to be modified and its type can be inferred . Here is the final version of the code:

```
var string = ""

let extracted_data = response?.extracted_data ?? []
string.append("\(extracted_data)")

print(string)
```

---

Perhaps you don't want the `[]` that prints when `response == nil`.  In that case, have `? :` return a `String` like so:

```
var string = ""

let extracted_data = response == nil ? "" : "\(response!.extracted_data)"
string.append(extracted_data)

print(string)
```

---

If you want to print just the first item of your `[Any]` array, and it can really be of any type, then you can do this:

```
var string = ""

let first = response?.extracted_data.first
let extracted_data = first == nil ? "" : "\(first!)"
string.append(extracted_data)

print(string)
```

Comment: by doing this let extracted_data = response?.extracted_data ?? [],  extacted_data will still be an [], but I wan only to display the first element so I basically do extracted_data.first

Comment: Your question did not state that you wanted to print only the first value.

Comment: What types of data does your `[Any]` array contain?